# jQuery boolean issue in validating field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to do a really simple validation just to see if there's something input in a text area using jquery.  I can't figure out why once I add a boolean it doesn't do anything.  I have the boolean in there so that the error message doesn't append multiple times if they tab/click through the field, later I'll also use the boolean to validate the required fields are filled out and enable the submit button.

```
var w=$("#part_description_input");

var wErr=new Boolean(false);


w.blur(function() {
    if (w.val()=="" && wErr=false) {
        $("#part_description_label").append("<label style='color:red;'> This field is required</label>");
        wErr=true;
    }
    else {
        $("#part_description_label").empty();
        $("#part_description_label").append("<label style='color:red;'>* </label>Enter a Description of Your Part:");   
        wErr=false;
    }

})
```

Here's a jsfiddle with everything in it: http://jsfiddle.net/2bwFS/

Comment: You have typo: wErr=false make it wErr==false

Comment: Thanks!  I need more caffeine.

Comment: use === , using == cause some problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `wErr=false` instead of `wErr==false` :)

Comment: Wow, two hours and I missed a stupid = sign...  thanks man, sorry for the derp question.